# Calculate nonzeros percentage for specific columns and each row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a the following dataframe:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john','mary','peter','jeff','bill','lisa','jose'], 'gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M'],'state':['california','dc','california','dc','california','texas','texas'],'num_children':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4],'num_pets':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3]})

    name gender       state      num_children  num_pets
0   john      M  california             2         5
1   mary      F          dc             0         1
2  peter      M  california             0         0
3   jeff      M          dc             3         5
4   bill      M  california             2         2
5   lisa      F       texas             1         2
6   jose      M       texas             4         3
```

I want to create a new row and column `pct.` to get the percentage of zero values in columns `num_children` and `num_pets`
Expected output:

```
    name gender       state      num_children  num_pets   pct.
0   pct.                              28.6%     14.3%     
1   john      M  california             2         5        0% 
2   mary      F          dc             0         1       50%
3  peter      M  california             0         0      100%
4   jeff      M          dc             3         5        0% 
5   bill      M  california             2         2        0%
6   lisa      F       texas             1         2        0%
7   jose      M       texas             4         3        0%
```

I have calculated percentage of zero in each row for targets columns:

```
df['pct'] = df[['num_children', 'num_pets']].astype(bool).sum(axis=1)/2
df['pct.'] = 1-df['pct']
del df['pct']
df['pct.'] = pd.Series(["{0:.0f}%".format(val * 100) for val in df['pct.']], index = df.index)
```

---

```
    name gender       state  num_children  num_pets  pct.
0   john      M  california             2         5    0%
1   mary      F          dc             0         1   50%
2  peter      M  california             0         0  100%
3   jeff      M          dc             3         5    0%
4   bill      M  california             2         2    0%
5   lisa      F       texas             1         2    0%
6   jose      M       texas             4         3    0%
```

But i don't know how to insert results below to row of `pct`. as expected output, please help me to get expected result in more pythonic way. Thanks.

```
df[['num_children', 'num_pets']].astype(bool).sum(axis=0)/len(df.num_children)
Out[153]: 
num_children    0.714286
num_pets        0.857143
dtype: float64
```

**UPDATE:** same thing but for calculation of sums, great thanks to @jezrael:

```
df['sums'] = df[['num_children', 'num_pets']].sum(axis=1)
df1 = (df[['num_children', 'num_pets']].sum()
                                       .to_frame()
                                       .T
                                       .assign(name='sums'))

df = pd.concat([df1.reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=''), df], 
                ignore_index=True, sort=False)
print (df)
    name gender       state  num_children  num_pets sums
0   sums                               12        18    
1   john      M  california             2         5   7
2   mary      F          dc             0         1   1
3  peter      M  california             0         0   0
4   jeff      M          dc             3         5   8
5   bill      M  california             2         2   4
6   lisa      F       texas             1         2   3
7   jose      M       texas             4         3   7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mean` with boolean mask by compare `0` values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), because `sum/len=mean` by definition, multiple by `100` and add percentage with `apply`:

```
s = df[['num_children', 'num_pets']].eq(0).mean(axis=1)
df['pct'] = s.mul(100).apply("{0:.0f}%".format)
```

For first row create new `DataFrame` with same columns like original and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together:

```
df1 = (df[['num_children', 'num_pets']].eq(0)
                                       .mean()
                                       .mul(100)
                                       .apply("{0:.1f}%".format)
                                       .to_frame()
                                       .T
                                       .assign(name='pct.'))

df = pd.concat([df1.reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=''), df], 
                ignore_index=True, sort=False)
print (df)
    name gender       state num_children num_pets   pct
0   pct.                           28.6%    14.3%      
1   john      M  california            2        5    0%
2   mary      F          dc            0        1   50%
3  peter      M  california            0        0  100%
4   jeff      M          dc            3        5    0%
5   bill      M  california            2        2    0%
6   lisa      F       texas            1        2    0%
7   jose      M       texas            4        3    0%
```

Comment: It's possible to add this row of percentages this way, but wouldn't using a separate dataframe for these percentages be more ideal?

Comment: @suicidalteddy - yes, it is possible, but here is necessary some data processing, so easier with Series. But it is possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome solution as always. May I ask, what if I want to calculate `sums` instead of `percentages`?

Comment: @ahbon - do you think change `s = df[['num_children', 'num_pets']].eq(0).mean(axis=1)` to `s = df[['num_children', 'num_pets']].sum(axis=1)` and then `df['pct'] = s` ?

Comment: I edited your code and it works for calculation of sums. Please check my updated question. Thanks.